# rdlc background color bug - large expression seems to cause a bug

Tags: asp.net, colors, expression, rdlc

I am working on designing a rather large rdlc report in ASP.Net MS visual 2010.  Some  rows in the report require the row to be highlighted if something is out of place.  So I went to the background colors tab in the Properties box of my rdlc report after clicking on the table row.  I am trying to get the following expression to work in the background color tab in the properties box.

```
`=IiF((Fields!C.Value < .75 And Fields!C.Value <> "") 
Or (Fields!S.Value < .75 And Fields!S.Value <> "")
Or (Fields!O.Value > 5), "Yellow", "White")`
```

---

Originally I want the background color either yellow or white, but for testing purposes I changed white to green since white is a default it seems.

```
`=IiF((Fields!C.Value < .75 And Fields!C.Value <> "") 
Or (Fields!S.Value < .75 And Fields!S.Value <> "")
Or (Fields!O.Value > 5), "Yellow", "Green")`
```

This caused some rows to be green, but none were yellow, the rows that should be yellow are instead white.

---

It works fine when I shorten it to

```
`=IiF((Fields!C.Value < .75 ), "Yellow", "Green")`
```

I get all Green and Yellow rows.

---

And it worked fine when I tried

```
`=IiF((Fields!C.Value < .75 And Fields!C.Value <> ""), "Yellow", "Green")
```

This worked fine too I get all rows being either Green or Yellow.

---

But as soon as I add an Or they stop working.

```
`=IiF((Fields!C.Value < .75 And Fields!C.Value <> "") 
Or Fields!O.Value > 5 , "Yellow", "Green")`
```

This results in some Green rows but no yellow rows, the should be yellow rows all come out white?

---

And in some cases I get no Green or Yellow rows.  I tired in versing the original statement,

```
`IiF((Fields!Cpk_C.Value >= .75 Or Fields!Cpk_C.Value = "") 
And (Fields!Cpk_S.Value >= .75 Or Fields!Cpk_S.Value = "")
And (Fields!Cpk_S.Value <= 5), "Green", "Yellow")`
```

but then nothing works as it's all white rows.

---

Any help in what I am doing wrong, or why this doesn't work, is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are those newlines actually part of your formula?

Comment: do newlines interrupt the expression?  I added them for readability.

Comment: or the ' (those aren't part of my expressions, they are used to indicate code)

Comment: Yeah it's VB-based so newline is the end-of-statement marker. You have to put a `_` right before each newline which means "this statement continues on the next line".

Comment: I did try =IiF((Fields!Cpk_C.Value > .75 And Fields!Cpk_C.Value <> ""), "Yellow", "LightGreen") all on one line, and I still get the same bug, no Yellow rows.

Comment: as in the would be Yellow rows all show up White

Comment: Ok fair enough. Something is probably happening with type conversions. What is the data type of Cpk_C?

Comment: Tired the main one all one line as follows =IiF((Fields!Cpk_C.Value < .75 And Fields!Cpk_C.Value <> "") Or (Fields!Cpk_S.Value < .75 And Fields!Cpk_S.Value <> "") Or (Fields!Cpk_S.Value > 5), "Yellow", "LightGreen") all one line, I end up with some LightGreen rows, but the other rows that should be Yellow are White

Comment: All values are decimal(10, 3)

Comment: The biggest part that confuses me is even if the formula is wrong, shouldnt all rows be either Yellow or LightGreen.  The fact that some rows come out white makes me think it's inserting it's own options.  Oh and that last formula I pasted wrong, the part that says Cpk_S.Value > 5 should be OOS.Value > 5.  Also OOC is Int

Comment: Discovered some warnings Warning: The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘Cpk_C’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)
Warning: The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘Cpk_S’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)
Warning: The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘OOC’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Comment: So yes it was a problem with the type.  It would work buggy from the <> "" values and cause those warnings.  so instead I used IsNumeric so =IiF((Fields!Cpk_C.Value > .75 And IsNumeric(Fields!Cpk_C.Value)) Or (Fields!Cpk_S.Value > .75 And IsNumeric(Fields!Cpk_S.Value)) Or Fields!OOC.Value > 5, "Yellow", "LightGreen") and it works find now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the comments above the problem was solved (thanks to a tip from Ic).  The issue had to do with the type of values the items C.Value and S.Value.  They were Decimal based and not string so a comparison to <> "" was causing a format warning which wouldn't execute the code on those rows resulting a no color applied as a result.  Since they were essentially floats the IsNumeric function was a better fit.

=IiF((Fields!Cpk_C.Value > .75 And IsNumeric(Fields!Cpk_C.Value)) Or (Fields!Cpk_S.Value > .75 And IsNumeric(Fields!Cpk_S.Value)) Or Fields!OOC.Value > 5, "Yellow", "White")

Comment: Glad you sorted this out